# Working with a third party tree object in TestComplete

Tags: delphi, testcomplete

I am trying to improve a script that contains a third-party Delphi tree of class TElTreeView.  I can locate the specified item I want to click and expand in the ElTree1 object but I cannot seem to access it by its index value via TC scripting.  I need for the item to be checked, expanded and a couple of the child items underneath it set accordingly.

If I just do the following...

```
w := p.frmOpts;
tvw := w.VCLObject('ElTree1');
tvw.Selected.Checked := true;
```

... then the line item that is highlighted by default when the window is opened will be checked.  I've tried a number of other things but am not so far having any luck.  I'm trying to avoid using Sys.Keys.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at this "http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/15139/"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your application with debug information so **TestComplete**'s **Debug Info Agent** can provide the tool with access to all native methods and properties of the control. Once TestComplete can find debug information, you can access tree items in this way:

```
procedure Test;
  ...
  w := p.frmOpts;
  tvw := w.VCLObject('ElTree1');
  tvw.Items.Item(1).Checked := true;
end;
```

Find details on how to correctly compile a Delphi application with debug information for TestComplete in the [Debug Info Agent](http://support.smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/12507/) help topic. Click the link corresponding to your version of Delphi to get the steps.

Also, you can vote for advanced support of your control in future versions of TestComplete in [this survey](http://support.smartbear.com/products/more-info/testcomplete-survey/).

**Update:**

Although TestComplete does not have an extended support for the **TElTreeView** control like for some other wide-spread tree view controls, it is posible to create script routines for working with the control at a high-level. These routines will use TestComplete's Open Application feature to work with the tree control via its native methods and properties. The below sample script demonstrates how this can be done.

```
function getTreeNode(tree, nodeName); forward;
function clickTreeNode(tree, node); forward;

procedure test;
var
  tree;
  nodeName;
  node;
begin
  tree := Sys.Process('ElTreeTest').VCLObject('Form1').VCLObject('ElPanel1').VCLObject('ElTree1');
  nodeName := 'Item B|Item BB|Item BBA';
  node := getTreeNode(tree, nodeName);
  if node <> nil then
    Log.Message(node.Caption)
  else
  begin
    Log.Error('Node "' + nodeName + '" not found');
    Runner.Stop;
  end;

  node.MakeVisible;
  node.Checked := not node.Checked;
  clickTreeNode(tree, node);
end;

function clickTreeNode(tree, node);
var
  x, y;
begin
  node.MakeVisible;
  x := (node.TextRect.Left + node.TextRect.Right) / 2;
  y := (node.TextRect.Top + node.TextRect.Bottom) / 2;
  tree.Click(x, y);
end;

function getTreeChildNode(rootNode, nodeName);
var
  i;
  item;
  nodeCaption;
begin
  result := nil;
  if rootNode = nil then
    exit;

  nodeCaption := aqString.GetListItem(nodeName, 0);

  for i := 0 to rootNode.ChildrenCount - 1 do
  begin
    item := rootNode.Children(i);
    if item.Caption = nodeCaption then
    begin
      result := item;
      break;
    end;
  end;

  if aqString.GetListLength(nodeName) > 1 then
    result := getTreeChildNode(result, aqString.DeleteListItem(nodeName, 0));
end;

function getTreeNode(tree, nodeName);
var
  rootNodeCaption;
  item;
  i;
begin
  aqString.ListSeparator := '|';
  rootNodeCaption := aqString.GetListItem(nodeName, 0);
  result := nil;

  for i := 0 to tree.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    item := tree.Items.Item(i);
    if item.Parent = nil then
    begin
      if item.Caption = rootNodeCaption then
      begin
        result := item;
        break;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  if aqString.GetListLength(nodeName) > 1 then
    result := getTreeChildNode(result, aqString.DeleteListItem(nodeName, 0));
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I am using a .tds file so it is probably my lack of knowledge that I can't figure it out.  :)

I am reading the following...
http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/15099/#LabelIndex

...And wondering how to set the item number defined as 'Item(1)' to work with the root of the tree?  It appears that the number defined selects child items of the selected tree, correct?  I've tried a few different things but that last line of code doesn't appear to do anything for me (although the test still passes in TC - go figure!).  

Thanks again!

Comment: Working with items of a tree view by their captions is possible for the controls supported natively by TestComplete. The TElTreeView control is not supported in this way, but you still can implement the needed functionality in a script. I have updated my answer with a sample of such a script.

Comment: Fantastic - thank you!  I've been playing with this today and almost have it working.  Question for you - I keep getting an 'unknown name' error with the .makevisible command.  What is it supposed to do?

Comment: One more...  if I comment out the .makevisible lines, I get stuck at textrect.  I can't locate the property using the TC explorer ("Unknown name - textrect" error when the script runs).  SO CLOSE!  Thanks again!

Comment: MakeVisible is a native method that expands all parent nodes of the specified node in order to make sure that it is visible on the screen. TextRect is a native property contaning the coordinates of the specified node's text within the tree control. If TestComplete cannot find these members then, most probably, the tool cannot find or read debug information for the tested application. To check whether TestComplete has read debug info, select the tree object in the Object Browser and check whether there is the 'Debug Agent' group of properties in addition to 'Standard', 'RTTI', etc.